# Integral of absolute value of dx

Tags: integration, absolute-value

How do you evaluate $\int_1^0\vert \mathrm{d}x\vert$ and what is the reason behind it? I've seen two answers:

1) $\vert 0\vert-\vert1\vert=-1$

2) $\vert0-1\vert=1$

So which one is it?

Comment: It is the second one.

Comment: @uniquesolution Really? It's so non-intuïtive. What is the reason/math behind it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the *definition* of $\int_1^0\vert \mathrm{d}x\vert\,$ that you are working with? First choice appears to assume that $\int\vert \mathrm{d}x\vert=|x|\,$, the second one that $\int_1^0\vert \mathrm{d}x\vert=\left|\int_1^0 \mathrm{d}x \right|\,$. Neither is common, so please provide context.

Comment: @dxiv Here is the context: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/340289/calculating-the-electric-field-in-a-parallel-plate-capacitor-being-given-the-po

Comment: In this context, we do not write $ \lvert dx \rvert$, we write $dx$ is the magnitude of an infinitesimal direction vector $d\vec{x}$ pointing in the direction of our line integral, that is $dx = \lvert \vec{x} \rvert$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This notation is incorrect - it is not defined and does not make sense.

Referring to the physics context that you provide, when we perform a line integral
$$ \int \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{x} $$

what this notation means is that we are integrating alone a directed path of integration, the dot product of a vector field with the infinitisimal vector pointing in the direction of our path. Note that, as we move along a path of integration, our direction vector may change

In the case of the problem you provided, the electric field is pointing horizontally to the right, so if we choose a straight path parallel to the electric field, oriented in the same direction (moving from left to right), the electric field and the direction vector of our integration path point in the same direction, always (our path doesn't change direction as we go):

Since the electric field and the direction vector always point in the same direction:
$$ \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{x} = E \, dx $$
What the left side means is the dot product of electric field with an infinitesimal direction vector and what the right side means is the magnitude of the electric field times an infinitesimal magnitude of length.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the notation. Integrals of the form $\int_A|d\mu|$ appear, as a matter of routine, in measure theory and elsewhere. Here $|d\mu|$ denotes the total-variance of the measure $d\mu$, and $A$ is a measurable set. In our context, it is clear to me that $A=[-1,0]$ and that the measure here is $|dx|$.

Comment: An example from physics to explain the total variation of a measure. A function that takes a region of space and gives the total electical charge in the region is a signed measure. The total variation of this signed measure counts also negative charges as positive. So if there are 5 mC of positive charges in a region and 7 mC of negative charges in the same region, the signed charge measure gives 5-7 = -2 mC while the total variation gives 5+7 = 12 mC.